# Inverse function of $f(x)=e^x+x-1$.

Tags: functions, exponential-function, inverse-function-theorem

Please find the inverse function of $f(x)=e^x+x-1$. I want to integrate the inverse functions of this but I am not able to find out any possible way to do so.

Comment: Will Lambert W function will play any role here

Comment: It does not have an explicit inverse as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve $y = e^x + x - 1$ for $x$ with the Lambert W function, as you suspected:
\begin{align*}
y = e^x + x - 1 &\implies y -x + 1 = e^x \\
&\implies (y - x + 1)e^{-x} = 1 \\
&\implies (y - x + 1)e^{y - x + 1} = e^{y + 1} \\
&\implies y - x + 1 = W(e^{y + 1}) \\
&\implies x = y + 1 - W(e^{y + 1}).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget there is a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) for integrating inverse functions! Depending on what you want the bounds of integration to be, you might not need to invert the function at all.

If $c = e^a + a - 1$ and $d = e^b + b - 1$, for any two reals $a$ and $b$, then

$$\int_c^d (e^x + x - 1)^{-1} dx + \int_a^b (e^x + x - 1) = bd - ac$$

More explicitly, for any $a$ and $b$ we have

$$
\int_{e^a + a - 1}^{e^b + b - 1} (e^x + x - 1)^{-1} = 
b(e^b + b -1) - a(e^a + a - 1) - (e^b - e^a + \frac{1}{2}(b^2 - a^2) - (b - a))
$$

There is also a formula (on the same page) for taking an antiderivative, rather than integrating with bounds. However the antiderivative formula is less useful because it requires a closed form for $(e^x + x - 1)^{-1}$, whereas the above formula allows us to compute (certain) integrals without ever looking at a $W$-function!

---

I hope this helps ^_^